# Why django return 302 error when i use a get param?

Tags: django, django-admin

I am trying to use a GET parameter that is not a field in the model, but I am getting a 302 error and then Django redirects to `?e=1`
How can I use a new get param not defined in the model fields to use it in my admin.py?

**EDIT:**
I want to pass a param in the url to use it then in a method in my admin.py
i.e.: `admin/<app_label>/<model_name>/?myparam=myvalue`
Then, override the *queryset* method to use request object to get this param from the url, and filter some fields in my model.
What I have seen is that if *myparam* is not a field from the model, I get a 302 error. But I cannot use a model field, because I want to use this *myparam* to compare it to several fields (too many fields to add them in the url).

Comment: You really have to share a tad bit more than that if you expect anyone to help you out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [site](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2322/) and defining a new form like `FormForAdvancedSearch` and overriding methods `lookup_allowed` and `changelist_view` it seems to work.

I make my queryset getting the url param from `other_search_fields` dictionary.

The only problem is that pagination will not keep the url param.